# LINQ query with sub-query on LEFT JOIN conditions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, left-join

I have these queries in SQL and LINQ that were built to retrieve the same data. Unfortunately they are retrieving different amount of records (LINQ returns 1555 values, and SQL returns 1969) and I can't figure out why.

Please help me to find out what I'm missing. Follows the queries:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT l.Lease_Detail_ID, l.Lease_ID, l.XRef_Lease_ID, v.Vendor_Name, l.Description, c.County, l.Amount, l.Payment_Due_Date,
    l.Lease_Type, l.Location_ID, l.Active, l.Expiration_Date, a.Authorized, p.Payment_Date
    FROM tblfLeaseDetail AS l
    LEFT JOIN tblvVendor AS v ON l.Vendor_ID = v.Vendor_ID
    LEFT JOIN tblvCounty AS c ON l.County_ID = c.County_ID
    LEFT JOIN tblfAuthorization AS a ON l.Lease_Detail_ID = a.Lease_Detail_ID
    AND a.Authorization_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 Authorization_ID
                            FROM tblfAuthorization
                            WHERE Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID
                            ORDER BY Authorized_Date)
    LEFT JOIN tblfPayment AS p ON l.Lease_Detail_ID = p.Lease_Detail_ID
    AND p.Payment_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 Payment_ID
                        FROM tblfPayment
                        WHERE Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID
                        ORDER BY payment_date)
    ORDER BY l.Lease_Detail_ID
```

**LINQ:** *(Edited after a few comments)*

```
var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                         join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID into lv
                         from jlv in lv.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID into lc
                         from jlc in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID into la
                         from jla in la.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where jla.Authorization_ID == (from aj in leases.tblfAuthorizations
                                                        where aj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                                        orderby aj.Authorized_Date ascending
                                                        select aj.Authorization_ID).FirstOrDefault()
                         join p in leases.tblfPayments on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals p.Lease_Detail_ID into lp
                         from jlp in lp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where jlp.Payment_ID == (from pj in leases.tblfPayments
                                                  where pj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                                  orderby pj.Payment_Date ascending
                                                  select pj.Payment_ID).FirstOrDefault()
                         select new LeaseViewModel()
                         {
                             Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID,
                             Lease_ID = l.Lease_ID,
                             XRef_Lease_ID = l.XRef_Lease_ID,
                             Vendor_Name = jlv.Vendor_Name,
                             Description = l.Description,
                             County = jlc.County,
                             Amount = l.Amount,
                             Payment_Due_Date = l.Payment_Due_Date,
                             Lease_Type = l.Lease_Type.ToString(),
                             Location_ID = l.Location_ID,
                             Active = l.Active,
                             Expiration_Date = l.Expiration_Date,
                             Authorized = jla.Authorized,
                             Payment_Date = jlp.Payment_Date
                         });
```

**EDIT:**

After analyzing the run-time SQL query generated by LINQ statement I found out that it's creating the Authorized sub-query in the wrong place. Here is what it looks like:

```
SELECT [t0].[Lease_Detail_ID], [t0].[Lease_ID], [t0].[XRef_Lease_ID], [t1].[Vendor_Name] AS [Vendor_Name], [t0].[Description], [t2].[County] AS [County], [t0].[Amount], [t0].[Payment_Due_Date], [t0].[Expiration_Date], [t3].[Authorized] AS [Authorized], CONVERT(NVarChar(1),[t0].[Lease_Type]) AS [Lease_Type], [t0].[Location_ID], CONVERT(Int,[t0].[Active]) AS [Active], [t4].[Payment_Date] AS [Payment_Date]
FROM [dbo].[tblfLeaseDetail] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tblvVendor] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Vendor_ID] = ([t1].[Vendor_ID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tblvCounty] AS [t2] ON [t0].[County_ID] = ([t2].[County_ID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tblfAuthorization] AS [t3] ON ([t0].[Lease_Detail_ID]) = [t3].[Lease_Detail_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tblfPayment] AS [t4] ON ([t0].[Lease_Detail_ID]) = [t4].[Lease_Detail_ID]
WHERE ([t4].[Payment_ID] = ((SELECT TOP (1) [t5].[Payment_ID] FROM [dbo].[tblfPayment] AS [t5] WHERE [t5].[Lease_Detail_ID] = ([t0].[Lease_Detail_ID]) 
                            ORDER BY [t5].[Payment_Date] ))) 
                            AND ([t3].[Authorization_ID] = (( SELECT TOP (1) [t6].[Authorization_ID] 
                                                                FROM [dbo].[tblfAuthorization] AS [t6] 
                                                                WHERE [t6].[Lease_Detail_ID] = ([t0].[Lease_Detail_ID]) 
ORDER BY [t6].[Authorized_Date] )))
```

The problem is that it only made more confuse, once Payment and Authorized joins have exactly the same structure.

Comment: Could it be the distinct operation on the linq query?  That would be my guess since it returns the smaller number of rows.

Comment: Just tried to remove it, it still retrieving the same. Thanks for trying to help, anyway!

Comment: I think SQL server does sorting in ascending order by default so that is one difference I see. in the SQL the sub queries are doing in ascending order but the LINQ is doing descending explicitly .. something to try if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Well observed, Sam! It didn't solve the problem, but certainly made the query better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The order of the Authorized and Payment subqueries doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research I finally found how to do it. Here is the LINQ query that generates the SQL I was trying to get:

```
var leaseList = (from l in leases.tblfLeaseDetails
                             join p in leases.tblfPayments
                             on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals p.Lease_Detail_ID into lp
                             from jlp in lp.Where(x => x.Payment_ID == (from pj in leases.tblfPayments
                                                                          where pj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                                                          orderby pj.Payment_Date ascending
                                                                          select pj.Payment_ID).FirstOrDefault()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join a in leases.tblfAuthorizations on l.Lease_Detail_ID equals a.Lease_Detail_ID into la
                             from jla in la.Where(x => x.Authorization_ID == (from aj in leases.tblfAuthorizations
                                                                                  where aj.Lease_Detail_ID == l.Lease_Detail_ID
                                                                                  orderby aj.Authorized_Date ascending
                                                                                  select aj.Authorization_ID).FirstOrDefault()).DefaultIfEmpty()                            
                             join v in leases.tblvVendors on l.Vendor_ID equals v.Vendor_ID into lv
                             from jlv in lv.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join c in leases.tblvCounties on l.County_ID equals c.County_ID into lc
                             from jlc in lc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             select new LeaseViewModel()
                             {
                                 Lease_Detail_ID = l.Lease_Detail_ID,
                                 Lease_ID = l.Lease_ID,
                                 XRef_Lease_ID = l.XRef_Lease_ID,
                                 Vendor_Name = jlv.Vendor_Name,
                                 Description = l.Description,
                                 County = jlc.County,
                                 Amount = l.Amount,
                                 Payment_Due_Date = l.Payment_Due_Date,
                                 Lease_Type = l.Lease_Type.ToString(),
                                 Location_ID = l.Location_ID,
                                 Active = l.Active,
                                 Expiration_Date = l.Expiration_Date,
                                 Authorized = jla.Authorized,
                                 Payment_Date = jlp.Payment_Date
                             });
```

Comment: You could make this useful for future readers by explaining what you changed essentially. Also it's better to show the changed lines only.

Comment: Basically what I changed were the joins with the sub-queries, Gert